# is there a way to parse claims from an expired JWT token?

Tags: java, jwt, json-web-token

If we try to parse an **expired** `JWT`, results in expired exception.

Is there a way to **read claims even the JWT was expired**.

Below is used to parse JWT in java:

`Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret.getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JWT objects are Base64URL encoded. This means that you can always read headers and payload by manually Base64URL-decoding it. In this case you will simply ignore `exp` attribute.

For instance you can do like this (I'm using Java8 built-in `Base64` class, but you can use any external library, such as [Apache Commons Codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/)):

```
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();
String src = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImV4cCI6IjEzMDA4MTkzODAifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.2GpoV9q_uguSg0Ku6peI5aZ2qBxO5qOA42zaS25gq_c";
String[] parts = src.split("\\."); // Splitting header, payload and signature
System.out.println("Headers: "+new String(decoder.decode(parts[0]))); // Header
System.out.println("Payload: "+new String(decoder.decode(parts[1]))); // Payload
```

and the output is:

```
Headers: {"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","exp":"1300819380"}
Payload: {"sub":"1234567890","name":"John Doe","admin":true}
```

Please note also that the `exp` attribute is set to `1300819380`, which corresponds to `16 january 2016`.

Answer (score 54):

There is a better approach to do this.
if you see JWT Exception handler object e.g. ExpiredJwtException, expection object itself contains the following:-
header, claims and message

so claims can easily extracted through this object i.e. `e.getClaims().getId()` where e is ExpiredJwtException object.

ExpiredJwtException consturct is as follow:-

```
public ExpiredJwtException(Header header, Claims claims, String message) {
        super(header, claims, message);
}
```

Example:-

```
    try{
        // executable code
   }catch(ExpiredJwtException e){
        System.out.println("token expired for id : " + e.getClaims().getId());
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

this might be old but for anyone whose facing this issue, the java's `io.jsonwebtoken`
 `ExpiredJwtException` already got the claims in it, you can get it by calling `e.getClaims()`.

Comment: The "the Java's" you speak of here is probably the JJWT library.

Comment: You're re-stating what @Gautam wrote two years prior...

Answer (score 4):

If you use `io.jsonwebtoken` you try my function:

```
public Claims getClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        try {
            // Get Claims from valid token
            return Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();
            
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            // Get Claims from expired token
            return e.getClaims();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Someone comes in looking for jose4j library then below works:

```
invalidJwtException.getJwtContext().getJwtClaims()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the ValidateLifetime property of the TokenValidationParameters to false before calling ValidateToken.

```
TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
tokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
ClaimsPrincipal principal = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);
```

Then you can read the claims like this:

```
string name = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Name)).Value;
string email = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email)).Value;
```